# Bad state: Future already completed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm getting this error with any flutter command on Big Sur:

```
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1102:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1109:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1130:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (6 tries left)
```

the only thing I changed was install AdGuard but I completely remove it. Now I can't get rid of this error after trying different methods to fix it.

I also have Bitdefender but don't think this is related because I had this install since very beginning (also this is a requirement from my company and I cannot modify anything here)

Comment: didn't help me but this might be a solution for some people: https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardForMac/issues/773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Try using `flutter config --no-analytics`. It should be working fine.

[Refrence](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40515#issuecomment-726878465).

**Approach 2:**

If you are using third party antivirus programs try to uninstall and reinstall the program or deactivate the option "Scan secure connection" on Web Shield (Core Shields)

Comment: That's one of the thing I tried and didn't work. Restarted IDE, laptop and everything

Comment: About the antivirus, AdGuard is removed and I cannot modify Bitdefender because it's blocked by my company

Comment: Commands work if I replace the whole flutter folder with the most updated one (I was using 1.22.6) BUT commands take for ever and after that they say "Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)". So at the moment I cannot use this version of use the most updated one

Comment: I've trying also some VPNs (I've read that flutter devs from China also have a similar issue) but nothing changed

Comment: So make sure if your company is banning the IP address of flutter servers @Dani

Comment: I started developing on this laptop with Bitdefender 1 year ago and never had any problem. Why now and how can I get that IP?

Comment: Also tried this and didn't work: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46641#issuecomment-798881215

Comment: IT disabled my Bitdefender and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yea good to hear that. I was looking for some other approches but nothing was coming in my mind... @Dani

Comment: The provide answer is not telling about solution. It's just workaround to not show error or warning in logs.